# SQL/PHP - Order by descending missing one entry

Tags: php, sql

Okay, so I have this query:

```
SELECT `data`, `time` 
FROM `adventurelogs` 
WHERE `username` = ? 
ORDER BY `time` DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

With this PHP code:

```
if($statement = $database->prepare($query)) {

    $statement->bind_param('s', $username);

    $statement->execute();

    $statement->bind_result($data, $time);

    $statement->fetch();

    while($statement->fetch()) {
        echo '<label title='.$data.'">'.$data.' - '.date('j\-M \@ h:i:s', $time).'</label><br>';
    }
}
```

This works, however, it is missing the most recent entry.

I could have these entries:

```
Entry 0
Entry 1
Entry 2
Entry 3
```

and it would only fetch:

```
Entry 1
Entry 2
Entry 3
```

Comment: You are losing your first row because you have $statement->fetch(); before you enter the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the `$statement->fetch();` above the while loop. It returns the first result, which is lost, because it's not assigned to any variable.